# Bootstrapping for intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC) in Stata

Tags: stata

I want to bootstrap confidence intervals when running the intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC) in Stata 13

I tried

```
bootstrap, reps(100) seed(1): icc ratings target judge, consistency
```

but this is not working.

Can anyone suggest the right code?

Comment: [this](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2008-04/msg00744.html) may help you

Comment: Not much considering that icc is in stata 13. I just need to bootstrap the confidence intervals in view of problems with normal distr.

Comment: You are not specifying what saved results you want to bootstrap. Do look at the help for `bootstrap` and the manual entry for `icc`.

Comment: I looked at help icc, it says bootstrap can be used it with it.

Comment: And can't get how to apply it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Stata 13; but here is my solution which I think this should work.

```
bootstrap ricc=r(icc_i), reps(100) seed(1): icc ratings target judge, consistency
```

where, `r(icc_i)` is the intraclass correlation for individual measurements; this is stored as scalar by Stata (see [here](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/ricc.pdf#riccRemarksandexamples)) which you can get by typing `return list` after running the model.

Comment: Thanks for this @Metrics, I'm running it before trying use the bootstrap - and the list is not showing' so ricc is not being recognised.

Comment: I don't know why @Metrics is recommending the wrapper `e()`. `icc` is r-class and leaves results like `r(icc_i)` in its wake.

Comment: @  Nick: I have now updated  that ; I hope it will work now. Thanks

Comment: @Metrics - Whilst I believe the code provided is now correct, I've insufficient observations to compute bootstrap standard errors.  Whats your suggestion? My aim was to create some form of non parametric CI given the small size issue.

Comment: May be [this](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2010-10/msg00232.html) answer on Stataslist can help you? Alternatively, you can post that as a new question with code and the output you got.